# Print as pdf in DevExpress RichEdit react

Tags: devexpress

I'm using DevExpress RichEdit in my React app.

Everything is working except for the printing.
I have added custom fonts which I can see is working in the editor, but as I understand it I need to use `PrintMode.Pdf` in order to get the same fonts when printing, at least it is not working right now with `PrintMode.Html` (default)

I have a fonts.css that looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Arimo';
  src: url(/src/fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf),
    url(/src/fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Italic.ttf), url(/src/fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Bold.ttf),
    url(/src/fonts/Arimo/Arimo-BoldItalic.ttf);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I've loaded the fonts using the `options.fonts` like this:

```
options.fonts = {
    defaultFolder: 'src/fonts/'
    fonts: [
        {
          name: 'Arimo',
          fontFamily: 'Arimo',
          italicFontUri: 'Arimo/Arimo-Italic.ttf',
          boldFontUri: 'Arimo/Arimo-Bold.ttf',
          boldItalicFontUri: 'Arimo/Arimo-BoldItalic.ttf',
          regularFontUri: 'Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf',
        },
     ],
    mappings: {
      defaultFontName: 'Arimo',
};
```

And in the end I set the print mode like this:

```
  const printSettings: IPrintingSettings = {
    mode: PrintMode.Pdf,
    closePrintDialogWithHtmlPreview: true,
  };

  options.printing = printSettings;
```

I have, along with all other imports, imported the pdfkit like this:

```
import 'devexpress-richedit/dist/pdfkit';
```

As I said, fonts works fine in editor, but when I try to print I get warnings saying:

```
OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135
```

And then error in the console saying:

```
pdfkit.js:52349  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown font format
    at Object.$a35dad4d16c8d1df$export$185802fd694ee1f5 (pdfkit.js:52349:11)
    at PDFFontFactory.open (pdfkit.js:42368:22)
    at PDFDocument.font (pdfkit.js:42420:33)
    at PdfBoxExporter.exportText (box-exporter.js:70:26)
    at PdfBoxExporter.export (box-exporter.js:28:18)
    at PdfLayoutRowExporter.export (row-exporter.js:26:30)
    at PdfLayoutPageAreaExporter.exportColumn (page-area-exporter.js:28:34)
    at page-area-exporter.js:18:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PdfLayoutPageAreaExporter.export (page-area-exporter.js:18:26)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:
I've seen comments like this in many places, so it should be something about how the font is loaded

> 1008813135 is <!DO in Latin encoding, which is, in all probability,
> the start of <!DOCTYPE

Update:
Problem seems to be related to the import of pdfkit

```
import 'devexpress-richedit/dist/pdfkit';
```

Comment: @KJ Yeah, that's probably incorrect, thank you for pinting that out! However I tried to both remove it and leave url:s to the other styles, and remove all the other styles and just keep the regular but I still get the same error.